# Google chart using JSON - Format issue - ASP.net - "Table has no columns”

Tags: asp.net, json, excel, vba

I am seeing 2 types of JSON format out there and getting really confused.

I a trying to do the following:

1. I have an excel model with a range
   Type    RV
   MRC 10
   CRC 20
   CVA 30
   OpRisk  0
2. Using ExCelToWeb vba function from cDataSet (http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json/excel-json-conversion), I convert this range to a JSON string. Output is as follows:

   ```
   {   "cDataSet":[      
      {
        "Type":"MRC",
        "RV":10
      },
      {
         "Type":"CRC",
         "RV":20
      },
      {
         "Type":"CVA",
         "RV":30
      },
      {
         "Type":"OpRisk",
         "RV":0
      }
   ]}
   ```
3. I save this into a text file called myData.json
4. In Default.aspx.cs, I have

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public static String GetDataJSON(){
     String myvar = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Serge\\Downloads\\GoogleChartExample\\GoogleChartExample\\myData.json");
     return myvar;
   }
   ```
5. I call the function from Java Script in Default.aspx

   ```
   google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           url: 'Default.aspx/GetDataJSON',
           contentType: 'application/json',
           data: {},
           async: false,
           success:
               function (response) {
                  console.log(response.d);
                  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.d);
                  var csv = google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data);
                  console.log(csv);
                  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('myChart1')).draw(data, { title: "MyChart1" });
               },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert(textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
               if (!$.browser.msie) {
                   console.log(jqXHR);
               }
       }
       });
   }
   ```

=> console.log(response.d) outputs my JSON string exactly as intended

=> console.log(csv) does not output anything

=> the google chart outputs a red box saying  “Table has no columns”

I understand that there are 2 types of JSON format. The one that google has in its example has "cols": [ , and "rows": [ . Does it mean that Google Chart / Dataset is not compatible with my format? Is there anyway for me to convert from one to the other?

Would I be better not to use JSON and export from excel -> cvs =>  a C# array ->  a google dataset?

Thank you very much.
Serge

Comment: What you have there is just a JSON representation of a 2 dimensional table. Google Viz data is a specific format. Take a look at http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/google-visualization/serializing-excel-data-for-google-charts from the same site.